# Easy way to make an Installation Profile

Tags: users, distributions, backups

I want to use my current website as an installation profile. I've set it up so it contains some useful content types, views and example content nodes. Is there a no-coding way to create an installation profile that would look exactly as my current site when installed?

Comment: Adding a comment as I don't have time for a full answer. Drush make and the features module should help yo out here.

Comment: +1. FYI, I also find http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate worthy of use, but of course doesn't do the full profile and you still have to port all your local to the server.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no one module that does all that **perfectly**. But depending on what your site is made of, there are a few modules that can come pretty close. [Profiler Builder](http://drupal.org/project/profiler_builder) is probably the closest thing to what your looking for.

> It builds the .info, .profile, .install, .make, and .make.example files
>   necessary to turn a site into a distribution / installation profile
>   and tar's them up as a download.

The [Features module](http://drupal.org/project/features) can also be very useful as it allows you to package together subsets of functionalities (e.g. modules and settings for an image gallery).

Comment: I found that the easiest way is to copy the codebase and remove the settings.php file and then copy the database content into a new database.